# Using an writestream directly to an IP and port in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sockets, stream

I'm trying to create an app that is able to send a .pdf-file directly to a printer from an iPhone. I'd like to create a raw socket connection. I should be able to open a stream to a specific IP-adress and a port. Then I'd like to throw that .PDF-file into the stream so the printer (or my server on the computer) receives it.

I've made a stream already using ftp. Ofcourse, printers don't handle ftp-protocols. That is why I want to send the data in a raw stream to the device's port.

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Printers can't handle raw PDF either. Normally you would have a printer driver inbetween, that does a conversion from your input format (not PDF, but a OS-specific format, e.g. [GDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface) on Windows).

Comment: Some printers can using an inbuild protocol in the printer's interpreter. When I'd send an .exe-file to that port, the printer would print a lot of pages with text (kinda like 'open with Notepad). But the printers I'm testing this app on, can handle a PDF directly on the port. But besides that, the question is more like how do I create that stream? I tried some socket-examples but I don't understand it at all :(

Comment: Nice... I wish my printer could do that... Does it also execute dynamic PDF content?

Comment: It's actually the Oce VarioPrint 1055. That's not the regular printer you'll be having in your room :D And I don't know about that, but I could test that after I get the plain PDF printing (or sending, in case the printer doesn't work after all) working...

Comment: What library have you used to create the FTP stream?

Comment: For FTP, I used CFNetwork. A ftp-stream can then be created using `CFWriteStreamRef ftpStream;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CocoaAsyncSocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) is really easy to use and has good documentation.  It is an objective-c wrapper around lower level socket primitives.  It sounds like all you need is to write data out to a socket.  If so then it is the easiest way to go.